# How do i update nested dictionaries in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some data, let's assume it looks like this:

```
arr = [10, 90, 45]
```

And a dictionary, looking like this:

```
mydict = {}
```

I want to append the data from `arr` to the dictionary and i would like to store it like this:

```
mydict = {{'one': 10}, {'one': 90}, {'one': 45}}
```

I tried a simple loop:

```
for x in arr:
    mydict.update({'one': x})
```

But that doesn't work, since it will just overwrite the records.

Is there any way to do this in Python?

Comment: This `mydict = {{'one': 10}, {'one': 90}, {'one': 45}}` is not a dictionary, actually is not valid Python. You could, however, use a list of dictionaries, something like this `mylist = [{'one': 10}, {'one': 90}, {'one': 45}]`

Comment: Yeah, i think that a list of dicts is what i'm looking for!

Comment: The code you post won't work *at all*, because `list.update` doesn't exist. `mydict` isn't a `dict`, despite its name. (It wouldn't work before, either, because you can't store a `dict` in a `set`.)

Comment: Syntactically, `{{'one': 10}, ..}` is fine; it just produces a `TypeError` when evaluated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply do:

```
arr = [10, 90, 45]

lst = []
for e in arr:
    lst.append({'one': e})

print(lst)
```

**Output**

```
[{'one': 10}, {'one': 90}, {'one': 45}]
```

Or if you prefer a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
lst = [{'one' : e} for e in arr]
```

Comment: Thank you! This is very clear. But what is the difference between using this method or the one suggested in the other answer, for example?

Comment: There just different ways of achieving the same, but in python3+ you should favor the use of list comprehensions over map, as map does not create a list.

Answer (score 1):

you can use map

```py
arr = [10, 90, 45]
arrName = ['one', 'two', 'tree']
dictionary = dict(map(lambda(x, y:{x: y}))
```

or zip

```py
arr = [10, 90, 45]
arrName = ['one', 'two', 'tree']
dictionary = dict(zip(arrName, arr))
```

Comment: Your `map` example isn't syntactically correct; it's not clear what sequence you meant to pass to `dict`.